# Unable to create multiple records in nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create a issue tracker. Which contains below structure.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const time = require('../libs/timeLib')

let newRecord =  new Schema(
    {
        title:{type: String, default: ''},
        issueType: [],
        description: {type: String},
        issueLocation: {type: String},
        createdBy: {type: String, index: true},
        issueId: {type: String, unique: true},
        issueCreatedOn: {type: Date, default: time.now()},
        status: {
            open: {type: Boolean, default: false},
            closed: {type: Boolean, default: false}
        },
        screenshots: []
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Record', newRecord)
```

I wrote the below code for creating a new record. I am able to create record for the first time.
But when I try to create the same for second time using createdBy as same. I get the below error
I am using Postman to interact with the API

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: issueTrackingDB.records index:
>   userId_1 dup key: { : null }

See the function created for creation below

```
let createIssue = (req, res)=>{

    let createNewRecord = () =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            let newIssue = new RecordModel({
                title: req.body.title,
                description: req.body.description,
                issueLocation: req.body.issueLocation,
                createdBy: req.body.fullName, 
                issueId: shortid.generate(),
                issueCreatedOn: time.now(),
            })

            let issueType = (req.body == undefined || req.body.issueType == null || req.body.issueType == '')? []: req.body.issueType.split(',')
            newIssue.issueType = issueType

            let screenshots = (req.body == undefined || req.body.screenshots == null || req.body.screenshots == '')? []: req.body.screenshots.split(',')
            newIssue.screenshots = screenshots

            newIssue.save((err, issueDetails)=>{
                if(err){
                    logger.error(err.message, ' recordsController, createIssue', 8)
                    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, "Failed To Create Issue", 500, null)
                    reject(apiResponse)
                } else {
                    issueDetails.status.open = true
                    resolve(issueDetails)
                }
            })
        })
    } // end create new record


createNewRecord((resolve)=>{
    console.log("Issue Created Successfully")
    let apiResponse = response.generate(false, "Issue Created Successfully", 
    200, resolve)res.send(apiResponse)
        })
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
    console.log("Some Error occured")
    res.send(err)
        })
} // end create new issue
```

Answer (score 0):

You've a unique key on "issueId: {type: String, unique: true}", ensure that the value change at each call or remove the unique key

Comment: I have used to shortid.generate() to get unique numbers.

Comment: also i tried removing unique:true and checked. I still get the same error.